# Detect file-type with the help of magic-file and rename file-suffix accordingly

Tags: rename, filenames, mime-types, file-format, file-command

I have a folder (the iPhone Backup) with various files without a suffix.

I want to run a batch process over these files, which detects each file's file-type (with the help of the magic-file database (*/usr/share/misc/magic* or *man file*), and automatically changes / renames its file-suffix (from a database file/mime-type<->suffix) accordingly.

Hours of Googling and StackExchange-Searching brought no results, due to the general nature of the involved keywords "file", "magic", "rename", etc. Help appreciated!

Comment: Btw, my original problem was solved, as there is a software, which reorganises that bunch of flat UID-named suffix-less files into a proper folder structure with proper filenames with suffixes. iPhone Backup Extractor (http://www.supercrazyawesome.com/).

Nevertheless it would be good to know how to automatically add file suffixes according to detected filetype of files without a file-suffix in their file-name.

Answer (score 1):

What does your type<-> suffix DB look like? It's not that trivial to interpret `file`'s output. I'll just assume:
 * that the first word file prints is sufficient
 * this word is the key in a file where each line contains : and value is the suffix we want

For bash I'd write a function that takes as an argument the file type and echoes the suffix:

```
MISTERIOUSFILEMIMETYPETOSUFFIXDB=/path/to/key/value/file

typetosuffix () {
    grep -E "^\s*$1:" ${MISTERIOUSFILEMIMETYPETOSUFFIXDB}| cut -d : -f 2
}
```

With that function you can

```
for f in $(find /path/to/iphone/backup -type -f)
do
    FILEWITHOUTSUFFIX = basename $f
    [ ${FILEWITHOUTSUFFIX} = ${FILEWITHOUTSUFFIX%.*} ] && continue #the file has a suffix after all
    TYPE=$(file $f | cut -f 2) #put type determining magic here
    SUFFIXITSSUPPOSEDTOHAVE=$(typetosuffix $TYPE) #fetch suffix from DB
    mv $f $f$SUFFIXITSSUPPOSEDTOHAVE #rename the file
done
```

Comment: I had hoped that the magic DB itself contains such a mapping of mime/file-types to file suffixes, and that there's a ready-made solution for this.

Still, thanks a lot for your approach.